# Receiving cancel event using Future in Combine

Tags: ios, swift, combine

When using a Future I'm not able to receive the cancel event.

```
Future<String, Never> { promise in
    promise(.success("Hello Stackoverflow"))
}
.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    .handleEvents(receiveCancel: {
        print("Cancel event received here")
    })
    .sink(receiveValue: { value in
        print(value)
    })
    .store(in: &disposeBag)

disposeBag.map { $0.cancel() }
```

Interestingly using a subject it's working and I'm getting the event.

```
let subject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

subject.send("Hello Stackoverflow")

    subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    .handleEvents(receiveCancel: {
        print("Cancel event received here")
    })
    .sink(receiveValue: { value in
        print(value)
    })
    .store(in: &disposeBag)

disposeBag.map { $0.cancel() }
```

So why is Combine behaving that way and how I can resolve this?

Comment: Futures execute their closures immediately, so I don't think the cancel can actually interrupt given that your promise succeeds immediately. See: https://forums.swift.org/t/cancel-combine-future/29634/4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Future perfoms its work once as soon as it's created, and it completes after fulfilling its promise. So in your code, by the time `$0.cancel` is called the Future has already completed.

A `PassthroughSubject` runs for a longer period of time because it can publish an infinite number of values, that's why you can capture the cancel.

If you delay the fulfilment of the promise you can capture the cancel event like you'd want:

```
var disposeBag = Set<AnyCancellable>()

Future<String, Never> { promise in
  DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    promise(.success("Hello Stackoverflow"))
  }
}
.eraseToAnyPublisher()
.handleEvents(receiveCancel: {
  print("Cancel event received here")
})
.sink(receiveValue: { value in
  print(value)
})
.store(in: &disposeBag)

disposeBag.map { $0.cancel() }
```

Note that the execution of the closure that's passed to the future isn't cancelled because it's already running. The subscription is just cancelled and you won't receive the result.

Comment: That makes totally sense. Thanks Donny.

Comment: Just want to add that this isn't the ideal way to defer the execution of a promise and adds an unnecessary queue hop within the promise function. Combine has a publisher that will do exactly what you want and it's called `Deferred`. If you wrap your `Promise` inside a `Deferred` block it will only execute the inner publisher on subscription: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/deferred

Comment: The intent of the asyncAfter was not to defer execution. It was only to demonstrate that the `cancel` event would then be captured.

If you want to delay execution of a Future until it receives a subscriber `Deferred` is indeed the way to go.